# Need code to add more than one calculated column color icon to a single page

Tags: 2010

I am using Sharepoint 2010 and do not have permissions to use SPD.  I found vbscript code to add color status for one calculated column.  I want to to be able to show more than one column's results.  Example, one column would calcuate priority ratings and another may calculate a reporting status.  I want to have these fields in one list form and display two individual results on the Web page.

Example:  1) Priority Field Choice selected as Low would display a green icon AND
2) Status Field Choice selected as "In progress" would dispaly as a yellow icon.  Is this possible?  If so, what would the code look like to do this?  Thanks.

Comment: Including the script or a link to a post with the script would help.

Answer (score 1):

Dave Paylor has a decent walkthrough here: http://paylord.wordpress.com/2012/05/05/xslt-dashboard/ Please feel free to try something and document the results here if this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: I will try the link you provided and let you know.  Thanks!